# Run method from ViewController A on ViewController B

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two ViewControllers : A & B. When user make change on ViewController A i want to make some changes on ViewController B.

Right now i am doing it in this way: for this changes i have special func in ViewController B and in viewWillApear method of ViewController B run this func each time the ViewController is opened.

Maybe I can perform it easier?

```
var GlobalVarB = 0

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
var localVarB = 0

func update() {
     if(localVarB != GlobalVarB) {
               localVarB = GlobalVarB
     //do something }
}

override func viewWillAppear() {
    update()
}
}
```

Comment: you can create property and store value this property .and use it viewC B
You can save data also in userdefault

Comment: do you mean - create property in ViewController B? This is what i am doing right now - maybe i didn't explain it properly. I thought i can run this method outside ViewController B.

Comment: you can use protocol

Comment: can you explain how? Is it easier than method I currently using?

Comment: What is method you are using? Please provide your code.

Comment: Maybe a notification fired from ViewController A which ViewController B listens for. You could add the updated content in a dictionary and send that as  `UserInfo` on the notification you're firing.

Comment: I added code that i am currently using.

Comment: http://codewithchris.com/learn-swift-from-objective-c-part3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSNotification:

In View controller B add this

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{

//Your rest of code then below statement

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:) 
            name:@"TestNotification"
            object:nil];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
     // If you don't remove yourself as an observer, the Notification Center
    // will continue to try and send notification objects to the deallocated
    // object.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

In View controller A

```
 - (void) youMethodToFireNotification
    {
         // All instances observing the `TestNotification` will be notified
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
            postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" 
            object:self];   //Object here can be any changed value or you can access viewController A instance by sending self.
    }
```

Comment: Although the Notification Center has its valid use cases, it is almost always the wrong choice in these kind of questions.

Comment: @Eiko: though it depends on the preference what to use, as it is not recommended by apple that we shouldn't use NSNotification for such purpose. thanks for your suggestion, you can add up your answer so that it it will be useful for us to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NotificationCenter to execute a method in ViewController B from ViewController A.

Create a method in View Controller B to Make changes as per changes in VC A and add observer for this notificaitonCenter in ViewController B viewDidLoad/ViewWillAppear as given below.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodName) name:@"notificationName" object:nil];
```

And Call the Post Notification from View Controller A when you make changes in View Controller A as below.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"notificationName" object:nil];
```

You can also pass some values using UserInfo as Dictionary.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Although the Notification Center has its valid use cases, it is almost always the wrong choice in these kind of questions.

Comment: Then what could be valid option for this issue?

Comment: Just wiring the view controllers up. Set a property, call a method on it. Maybe pass it through some other instance higher in the hierarchy. Notifications are for very rare cases where direct messaging would be inappropriate. A very lose coupling where one component shouts "oh, by the way, this and that happened", and some other component might or might not be listening to that. If you're using it for ordinary messaging, something is seriously broken.